# Ruby on Rails - reverse add_column, add_index migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have associations set up in survey model as follows

```
attr_accessible :name, :questions_attributes
has_many :questions
```

and in question model

```
attr_accessible :content, :survey_id, :answers_attributes
belongs_to :survey
```

I have a migration that adds question_id to survey table
but I came to realise that this migration wouldn't be necessary as
I have already defined their associations in the model.
Is my understanding correct?

If my understanding is correct, I would like to reverse that migration.

I have added the last 2 lines starting with `remove` and ran `rake db:migrate`
but it doesn't do anything.

```
def change
    add_column :surveys, :question_id, :integer
    add_index :surveys, :question_id
    remove_column :surveys, :question_id, :integer
    remove_index :surveys, :question_id
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def up
  add_column :surveys, :question_id, :integer
  add_index :surveys, :question_id
end

def down
  remove_index :surveys, :question_id
  remove_column :surveys, :question_id
end
```

The up method is executed on `rake db:migrate`, the down method is executed on `rake db:rollback`
You cannot rely only on the `change` method, because of the order in which the rollback needs to be done(first remove index, then remove column)

edit:
Actually, you can do it with just `change` in Rails 3.2+

```
def change
  add_column :surveys, :question_id, :integer
  add_index :surveys, :question_id
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you want to rollback the migration. If so then you can use the below syntax for that

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n

       or


rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<version_number_of_migration>
```

which rollsback the particular migration

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. So was it not necessary to add this index to associated table in the first place as they are defined in the models already?

Comment: You mean question_id in survey table?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if adding this column was necessary when associations are defined in the model

Comment: You can find usefull information  about relationships in
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. In the question table you need survey_id but viceversa ins not required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its always neccessary to write a migration to add question_id in survey table

Only Declaring Associations is not enough

Your migrtaion should like this

def change
  add_reference :surveys,:question ,index : true
end

At any point rollback the migration if you have changes only in your system. Dont try to rollback once these migrations are ran in different environments

To rollback rake db:migrate:rollback VERSION="timestamp of migration file"